# Getting pattern matching working in older versions of python

Tags: python, list, jython

Consider the below piece of code:

```
searchList=["hello", "hello world", "world"]
pattern = 'hell'
matchingList = [t for t in searchList if re.match(pattern, t)]
```

The above code works fine in Jython 2.4.3 but fails in lower versions of Jython with this error:

```
ValueError: iterator indices must be consecutive ints starting at 0
```

Any workarounds?

With this below work around, am gettign the same error:

```
  for t in searchList:
      if re.match(pattern, t):
          matchingList.append(t)
```

Error seen in Jython 2.1

Comment: I guess the most obvious solution might be to re-write the list comprehension as a for loop?

Comment: List comprehensions were added in Python 2.0; how far back did you go? Or is it perhaps Jython you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works fine on cpython 2.3.5, 2.2.3, 2.1.3, and 2.0 as well as jython 2.2.1, 2.2, and 2.1. [List comprehensions are only available in 2.0+](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.0.html#list-comprehensions). Instead, you can write:

```
# Warning: This code is unnecessarily complex because of cpython 1.x (!) support
import re
searchList=["hello", "hello world", "world"]
pattern = 'hell'
matchingList = []
for t in searchList:
    if re.match(pattern, t):
        matchingList.append(t)
```

That being said, **even 2.4 is ancient** and has been unsupported for quite a while (this means that you must manually apply and adapt all security patches since then to have a secure system). The Python versions you're catering to are *more than a decade* old, and almost certainly riddled with security vulnerabilities. Consider deprecating Python 2.5 and older.

Comment: On which Python version are you? And which implementation: cpython, jython, IronPython, pypy, or something else?

Comment: Just as an aside: `re.match()` only matches at the start of strings, so it happens to work here but if pattern were `'world'`, it would only match the third string in `searchList`.

Comment: Why? Jython 2.5.3 is the current stable release.

Answer (score 0):

After much of a debugging, i found that the problem occurs when you try to iterate over the same list second time. and this issue has been reported here:

http://bugs.jython.org/issue1544224

I used the workaround mentioned in the above link and it works fine.

Thanks a lot, folks

Comment: In the example code, you're not iterating over any list twice. And after some struggles, I got jython 2.1 running, but I don't get the error. Are you sure that's the right bug?